# Speech recognition project

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'm making my final year project i.e. speech recognition. but I don't have any idea how to start.  I will use c#.  Please can anyone guide me how to start?  what should be the first step?

Thanks

Comment: Google was of no help to you whatsoever?

Comment: first, you should probably get a microphone for you computer

Comment: Your first step should be to clean up this question (as a sign of respect for your future professional colleagues).

Comment: @Anon.:  Especially when you factor in "valid" misspellings...

Comment: the purpose of language is to convey meaning, if you can easily understand the question then the language has succeeded in it purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to start with the wikipedia entry on speech recognition here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition - at the end of that article, there are a bunch of useful links to papers and software on the topic.

Another thing you will want to do is talk to the professor who is coordinating this project. He or she will know about other resources and can probably point you in a good direction.

Also - whenever embarking on a project you know nothing about, google is your friend

Answer (score 2):

Speech recognition is really fuzzy pattern-matching, so how about looking into artificial neural networks as they're extremely good at pattern matching. Ensure that the audio's in a nice simple format and trim to syllables/words. Train the network on these files and then find a way to split the files you record in code. It may be simplest to start with a very limited vocabulary (individual letters maybe) as a proof of concept. Be prepared to run computers overnight to train the networks and try to get access to a high performance cluster.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by researching some libraries and reading up on these subjects..

http://www.microsoft.com/speech/evaluation/thirdparty/engines.mspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/TTSinVBpackage.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2006/10/31/909044.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ssrinivas/SpeeechRecognitionusingCSharp11222005054918AM/SpeeechRecognitionusingCSharp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the .Net System.Speech.Recognition namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this MSDN article which describes the Speech libraries built into Windows Vista and Windows 7: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx